# Google Sheets - Reformat date on form submission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, null, typeerror

**The problem**

I have a Google form that is correctly logging data into a Google Sheet. However the format of the date when logged to Google Sheet is *DD/MM/YYYY*.

**Desired outcome**

To format the date as *MM/DD/YYYY* whenever a new form submission is made (So whenever a new row is created).

**What I have so far**

A working form which logs the date

[image]

There is the ability to run a script when a [form trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) is made. Heres what I have so far for my app script:

**Code.gs**

```
function respondToFormSubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Format column I
  var column = sheet.getRange("B:B");

  // Set new date format on column I
  column.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy');
};
```

**Current error I'm getting**

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheets" of null.
```

I'm not sure why its returning `null` as the current script is correctly linked to the Google Form.

How can I get to my desired outcome where column B has a date format of *MM/DD/YYYY* when a new form submission is made?

Comment: Is your script form-bound or spreadsheet-bound? If latter, the 'getActiveSpreadsheet()' method won't work. You should use form.getDestinationId() to get the id of the target spreadsheet and then open it by calling SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:

> I'm not sure why its returning null as the current script is correctly linked to the Google Form.

If your script is linked to the Google Form, the 'getActiveSpreadsheet()' method won't work. The script must be bound to a Google Spreadsheet for this method to execute. For form-bound scripts, use this code:

```
var ssId = form.getDestinationId();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
```

Also, setting the number format each time new form entry is submitted is redundant, You can simply select the entire B:B range, go to Format -> Number -> Custom number formats and enter dd/mm/yyyy. Each new form submission will be formatted automatically.

Comment: Format the cell does not work. I had tried that. It will only format existing cells but not new rows. I will try `.getDestinationId();`

Comment: @sam Yes, apparently it's a known issue in Google Sheets [link](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0AvCVYG7aDDA/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2FAvCVYG7aDDA). You can create another sheet and link to the form response sheet with a query formula  =QUERY(FormSheet!A:B, "SELECT *"). You can then apply custom format to all values. The values will update when new responses are submitted